# l2tp, ps3mediaserver

Tags: networking, 13.10, vpn, iptables, ps3

What im trying to do here are to connect to an PS3 Mediaserver, thats located remotely behind an VPN.

this is how my network looks like

```
PS3 Mediaserver:  IP: 10.0.0.116

Playstation 3:    IP 192.168.1.116
```

I'm connecting to the remote network, using an Drytek vigor 2920N. Site to site (LAN to LAN). 
[image: This is how my Lab looks like]

The issue here, arent that i cant connect to the PS3 Media server. the issue are that the PlayStation 3, does not se the PS3 media server on the "VPN network" since its on an other IP range. It looks like the play station is only looking for Media servers on its own network range.

I can ping 10.0.0.116, connect to it using ssh from an other computer on the 192.168.1.0/24 network.

So my Questions are:

How can i Masquerade  the 10.0.0.116 IP as 192.168.1.* on my local network.
Or if anyone know how i can get the PS3 to look for media servers on other network ranges, that would be an equally good solution for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

I installed NFS on one of my Ubuntu servers.

Installed PlayStation media server locally on my network.

and mounted the NTF file storage on the PlayStation media server.

tested whit both AVI and MVK files, and they are streamed whiteout any shuttering. on my 30/30 fiber connection. Still remain to test this setup whit blue ray.

[image]